# Show Image position on textView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, position

I want to show left and right position from an ImageView on a textView but when I run, it says the image cant be null

```
    val x = imageView.left
    val y = imageView.right

    textView.text = "left: $x right: $y "
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? We're not seeing your error message and the problem is not clear either.

Comment: i want to know the postion from an image but when i try to run it  log shows "imageView must not be null"

Comment: How do you initialize `imageView`?

Comment: i just call it from my xml

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are calling imageView from a lifecycle method in which the views are not initialized yet? For example, doing that on fragment's `onCreateView` instead of `onViewCreated` will throw a similar error.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem but now I wanted the image to collide with a moving object and show in the text that it collided but when I try to run the text doesn't show that it collided